# how to display all elements in queue?

Tags: c, queue

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define max 100

char name[max][80], data[80];
int front = 0;
int rear = 0;

int enqueue();
int dequeue();
int peek();
void display();

int main() {
    int value;
    int ch;
    printf("------------------------------\n");
    printf("\tMenu");
    printf("\n------------------------------");
    printf("\n [1] ENQUEUE");
    printf("\n [2] DEQUEUE");
    printf("\n [3] PEEK");
    printf("\n [4] DISPLAY");
    printf("\n------------------------------\n");
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Choice : ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        switch(ch) {
            case 1 : // insert
                printf("\nEnter the Name : ");
                scanf("%s",data);
                value = enqueue(name, &rear, data);
                if(value == -1 )
                    printf("\n QUEUE is Full \n");
                else
                    printf("\n'%s' is inserted in QUEUE.\n\n",data);
                break;
            case 2 : // delete
                value = dequeue(name, &front, &rear, data);
                if( value == -1 )
                    printf("\n QUEUE is Empty \n");
                else
                    printf("\n Deleted Name from QUEUE is : %s\n", data);
                printf("\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                value = peek(name, &front, &rear, data);
                if(value != -1)
                {
                    printf("\n The front is: %s\n", data);
                }
                break;
            case 4:
            display();
              break;
            case 5 : exit(0);
            default: printf("Invalid Choice \n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int enqueue(char name[max][80], int *rear, const char data[80]) {
    if(*rear + 1 == max)
        return -1;
    strcpy(name[*rear], data);
    (*rear)++;
    return 1;
}

int dequeue(char name[max][80], int *front, int *rear, char data[80])
{
    if(*front == *rear)
        return -1;

    strcpy(data, name[(*front)++]);
    return 1;
}

int peek(char name[max][80], int *front, int *rear, char data[80]) {
    if(*front == *rear) {
        printf(" QUEUE IS EMPTY\n");
        return -1;
    }
    strcpy(data, name[*front]);
    return 1;
}

void display(char name[max][80], int *front, int *rear, char data[80])
{
    if(*front == -1 || *front > *rear)
    {
        printf("\n QUEUE IS EMPTY");
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = *front; i<= *rear; i++)
        {
            printf("\t %s",data[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Student here.

I need to display all elements inside the queue, but my program ends whenever I click option number 4, For example, the user inputs four names, "Jennie, Lisa, Jisoo, Rose", when the user selects option number 4, the program should print all 4 names. Even though I only input one name and need to print it, the program just ends. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I provided similar advise on earlier questions:

1. Your prototypes are incorrect (either fix them or delete them and move the definitions before use).  I removed the prototype of `display()` and moved the implementation before use.
2. As your prototypes are wrong your compiler doesn't complain when you call `dislay()` without arguments (yours requires 4 arguments).
3. As `display()` doesn't change `name`, `front`, or `rear` I suggest you make first one const, and the other two integers.  `data` is not used so eliminate it.
4. `display()`: queue is empty if `front` and `rear` have the same value.
5. Eliminate the global variables in favor of local variables in `main()`.

Here is your working program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define max 100

char name[max][80], data[80];
int front = 0;
int rear = 0;

int enqueue();
int dequeue();
int peek();

void display(const char name[max][80], int front, int rear) {
    if(front == rear) {
        printf("\n QUEUE IS EMPTY");
        return;
    }
    for(int i = front; i < rear; i++)
    {
        printf("\t %s", name[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int value;
    int ch;
    printf("------------------------------\n");
    printf("\tMenu");
    printf("\n------------------------------");
    printf("\n [1] ENQUEUE");
    printf("\n [2] DEQUEUE");
    printf("\n [3] PEEK");
    printf("\n [4] DISPLAY");
    printf("\n------------------------------\n");
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Choice : ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        switch(ch) {
            case 1 : // insert
                printf("\nEnter the Name : ");
                scanf("%s",data);
                value = enqueue(name, &rear, data);
                if(value == -1 )
                    printf("\n QUEUE is Full \n");
                else
                    printf("\n'%s' is inserted in QUEUE.\n\n",data);
                break;
            case 2 : // delete
                value = dequeue(name, &front, &rear, data);
                if( value == -1 )
                    printf("\n QUEUE is Empty \n");
                else
                    printf("\n Deleted Name from QUEUE is : %s\n", data);
                printf("\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                value = peek(name, &front, &rear, data);
                if(value != -1)
                {
                    printf("\n The front is: %s\n", data);
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                display(name, front, rear);
                break;
            case 5 : exit(0);
            default: printf("Invalid Choice \n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int enqueue(char name[max][80], int *rear, const char data[80]) {
    if(*rear + 1 == max)
        return -1;
    strcpy(name[*rear], data);
    (*rear)++;
    return 1;
}

int dequeue(char name[max][80], int *front, int *rear, char data[80])
{
    if(*front == *rear)
        return -1;

    strcpy(data, name[(*front)++]);
    return 1;
}

int peek(char name[max][80], int *front, int *rear, char data[80]) {
    if(*front == *rear) {
        printf(" QUEUE IS EMPTY\n");
        return -1;
    }
    strcpy(data, name[*front]);
    return 1;
}
```

and sample session:

```
------------------------------
        Menu
------------------------------
 [1] ENQUEUE
 [2] DEQUEUE
 [3] PEEK
 [4] DISPLAY
------------------------------
Choice : 1

Enter the Name : test

'test' is inserted in QUEUE.

Choice : 1

Enter the Name : test2

'test2' is inserted in QUEUE.

Choice : 4
         test    test2
```